# Matplotlib pyplot Save Multiple Images from a Tensor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have images in a batch tensor (B, H, W, C) and I would like to save them on a folder one by one with different names.

```
for t in range(0,batch_size):
    a = target_silhouette[t].cpu().numpy()
    plt.savefig("./test.png")
    plt.imshow(a)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a function

```
def plot_image(image):
    image_save = image.cpu().numpy()    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    plt.grid("off");
    plt.axis("off");
    plt.imshow(image_save)
```

and then use this loop

```
plot_period = 1
for t in range(0,3):
  new_image = target_silhouette[t]
  if t % plot_period == 0:
   plot_image(new_image)
   plt.savefig( "\test" + str(t) + ".png")
```

Answer (score 1):

if your codes works change it like this:

```
import os
d,n = os.path.split(__file__)
for t in range(0,batch_size):
    a = target_silhouette[t].cpu().numpy()
    plt.savefig(d + "\\test" + str(t) + ".png")
    plt.imshow(a)
```

Comment: I added my progress below, I should add your function to that def. Any help?

Comment: Thanks, I combine your help to the final solution